# Como fazer um redirecionamento http para https

Tags: htaccess

Bom com certeza já deve haver uma pergunta bem parecida com esta no stackoverflow.

Mas antes de marcarem como duplicata, eu tenho uma especificação que pelo qual eu não achei nenhuma pergunta "igual" a esta que vou fazer.

Bom eu pretendo é o seguinte:

Eu tenho vários domínios cujo virtualhost apontam para o mesmo path físico `/www/site/public_html`.

Contudo o domínio exemplo.com, comprei ssl e o mesmo tem https.

O que pretendia fazer era um arquivo htacess que me fizesse redirecionar os http:// e os www para https para o meu dominio exemplo.com.

Contudo não quero que os outros domínios sejam afetados, ou seja não quero que os outros domínios fiquem com https.

Resumindo:

Fazer 1 condição que se o utilizador vier de http:// exemplo.com ou www.exemplo.com redirecionar automaticamente para https:// exemplo.com contudo, se vier de outro dominio não fazer nada.

Como isso seria possível de se fazer?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo.bar
    Redirect / https://www.foo.bar/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.foo.bar
    # ... Configuração SSL
</VirtualHost>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Alguem, pode me ajudar?

Comment: Gonçalo, sua pergunta foi respondida?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Essa é uma alternativa bem simples:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Se preferir que vá tudo para o sem `www`, troque a última linha por

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Se preferir manter o `www` igual digitado, troque a última linha por

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Lembrando que se você puser o certificado no mesmo IP dos sites SEM certificado, e alguém tentar acessar `https://site-sem-certificado.com.br` vai dar erro de qualquer jeito, pois a negociação do SSL vem **antes** do Apache processar a página.

<strike>E é por isso que site com HTTPS se coloca em IP exclusivo (ou se gasta dinheiro com certificados pra múltiplos domínios).</strike>

<sub>edit: já faz um tempo que os navegadores negociam o nome do do domínio no handshake, então é muito comum termos vários domínios no mesmo IP (ainda tem casos de "misturar" que vão dar problema com certificado errado). Na época da resposta ainda era problemático contar com esse suporte para coisas importantes. Ainda, com alternativas gratuitas como Let's Encrypt, é recomendável ter HTTPS em tudo.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

[RewriteRule não é mais recomendado de acordo com a documentação do Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect).

Para obter o mesmo efeito, o método recomendado é o `redirect`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Você precisará então também configurar o serviço que oferecerá HTTPS:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/ca.pem  # Se estiver utilizando um certificado auto-emitido, omita essa linha
</VirtualHost>
```

[Fonte.](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/ssl-apache2-debian-ubuntu)

Comment: +1 Eu gosto dessa solução, o problema é só a falta do "coringa" pra links internos (mas num site que "nasceu do zero" com SSL isso nao é um problema).

Comment: @Bacco concordo, desconheço métodos para redirecionamento condicional via `VirtualHost`.

Comment: No servername coloco o unico site que quero que redirecione?

Comment: @Gonçalo Exatamente. Substitua www.site.com e www.example.com pela URL do seu site único.

Comment: Certo, copio os 2 trechos de código e coloco em um arquivo htacess? Se sim, porque não abrimos o virtualhost apenas 1x?

Comment: @Gonçalo Porque o primeiro é mapeado para seu site http (porta 80), e o segundo para seu site https (porta 443).

Comment: Vou experimentar, um momento!

Comment: Não funcionou, deu internal server error, vou postar o meu arquivo htacess.

Comment: @Gonçalo ajudaria se você postasse a mensagem de erro completa. Adicionalmente, a área marcada como `# ... Configuração SSL` deve ser substituída e propriamente configurada. Vou adicionar um exemplo.

Comment: A unica coisa que me poseram na host foi um arquivo .txt, como faço a anexação?

Comment: observação, a documentação não afirma que não é recomendado usar o `mod_rewrite` para resolver a questão em contexto, mas diz que quando for possível resolver com o `mod_alias`, é preferível que use-o ao invés do `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @Gonçalo, o código é para o httpd.conf do apache e não para o htaccess.