# Meu site não é redirecionado para https

Tags: php, htaccess

Estou tentando fazer meu site redirecionado para o htpss, mas não o estou obtendo.

abaixo está o código em htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.lotericapremiada.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /index.php
```

Comment: O rewritebase esta errado provavelmente.

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma alternativa bem simples:

```html
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Se preferir que vá tudo para o sem www, troque a última linha por:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Se preferir manter o www igual digitado, troque a última linha por:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Lembrando que se você puser o certificado no mesmo IP dos sites SEM certificado, e alguém tentar acessar https://site-sem-certificado.com.br vai dar erro de qualquer jeito, pois a negociação do SSL vem antes do Apache processar a página.

E é por isso que site com SSL se coloca em IP exclusivo (ou se gasta dinheiro com certificados pra múltiplos domínios).

[tirei essa resposta daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142235/como-fazer-um-redirecionamento-http-para-https)

Answer (score -1):

O meu funciona com esse código

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Boa sorte

Comment: Coloquei o mesmo código, simplesmente aparece ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Eu copiei do meu .htaccess em produção. Muito estranho, esse é o seu site mesmo? lotericapremiada.com.br?

Comment: isso, já tentei de todas as formas, mas sem sucesso!

Comment: RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
            RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteBase /index.php

Comment: Eu verifiquei que quando acesso seu dominio não roda o site, verifique se no apache está habilitada a função rewrite_module. Somente assim ele respeitará as regras .htaccess